# Does Consul Automatically remove services after a certain time if the health check was failing

Tags: consul

I searched around and this seems not possible but I want to confirm I didnt miss anything. We are registering an application with consul. When the service dies does it get automatically removed after certain time. If that is possible is the option configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the check registering parameter [DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/check#deregistercriticalserviceafter) would meet your requirement

Comment: I dont really remember the exact issue anymore but that seems like a possible solution. I am going to mark as accepted answer.